# .NET Core with applicationInitialization & Kestrel

Tags: windows, iis, .net

Does kestrel support the applicationInitialization feature ?

This is the feature were you can define a page (or pages) that will will be executed after the application starts. Basically to warm up the application.

If it is not supported is there an equivalent for Kestrel ?

Comment: If such a feature can be even used for PHP sites, http://ruslany.net/2015/09/how-to-warm-up-azure-web-app-during-deployment-slots-swap/ I don't see a reason why it cannot be used for ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @LexLi it can if you use IIS but I’m using Kestrel standalone.

Comment: Then technically speaking, application initialization is not needed for that scenario. IIS needs it, so it can show a warning page, before ASP.NET/PHP finishes initialization. But when you run Kestrel, anyway you need to wait till the whole initialization finishes, and no possibility to warm it up. That's exactly why you need to put Kestrel behind a reverse proxy server (such as IIS).

Comment: @LexLi every point you made is wrong. It is needed for this scenario because I’ve tested it, the first hit has a performance penalty. Warning pages don’t apply to me, warning pages are not the only reason to warm up. That’s not exactly why one should put it behind a reverse proxy.  Even if you put it behind a reverse proxy there is no warm up done - IIS is not the only web server out there - so if you put it behind apache or nginx how do you solve the warm up problem - do you see how what you say makes no sense.

Comment: "Warning pages don't apply to me", but that's all you can get from IIS (or other servers if they have a similar feature). Microsoft has no plan yet to implement the kind of "warmup" you like, https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/809 you can refer to multiple threads or create your own to ping Microsoft developers, if that makes more sense to you.

Comment: @LexLi thanks for that link, appears others are asking the same thing as me :).  I have a solution of pinging some requests but as discussed in that link it is not the best solution. This seems to be an oversight, there needs to be an option that looks through app and loads all the necessary assemblies ahead of time as mentioned in that link.

Comment: @LexLi if you answer and use that link I’ll accept it. I guess I’ll just stick to the solution of pinging it for now. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we turn back the time, most people use scripts to ping pages so their web applications can be warmed up. Later Microsoft developed Application Initialization module for IIS 7.5 and above to simplify that (and with some extra functionality like showing a warning page).

However, if we change the scope to Kestrel, then Microsoft has no plan yet to implement similar functionality, as the GitHub threads like [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/809) revealed.

You can use pinging as a workaround, and wait to see if Microsoft changes their minds. They did so when porting URL Rewrite functionality to Kestrel, as a [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?tabs=aspnetcore2x).

Again, ASP.NET Core is open source, so maybe someone can step in to implement such a middleware.